# Project multiple documents from a field's value using aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider this document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d06614070b7f2b117b23db"), 
    "name" : "joe", 
    "value" : 3, 
}
```

I need to get the following aggregation result :

```
[{ 
    "name" : "joe", 
},
{ 
    "name" : "joe", 
},
{ 
    "name" : "joe", 
}]
```

Do you have an idea on how to do that with aggregation framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "name": { 
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$range": [0,"$value"] },
        "in": "$name"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$name" }
])
```

That essentially supplies `[0,1,2]` as in input array to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), from which you can emit each value of `"name"` repeated. So the `"$value"` field in the document is being used as the upper bound or "length" of the array to produce.

Not really any other option if your MongoDB does not support that, other than you simply transform on the cursor instead.